# Help on 'varying' and 'uniform' keywords in GLSL (OpenGL 4+)

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I want to use a shader just for learning purposes but I have a few questions about it.

I have the following code:

**Vertext shader:**

```
const float Eta = 0.66;         // Ratio of indices of refraction 
const float FresnelPower = 5.0; 

const float F  = ((1.0-Eta) * (1.0-Eta)) / ((1.0+Eta) * (1.0+Eta));

varying vec3  Reflect;
varying vec3  Refract;
varying float Ratio;

void main()
{
    vec4 ecPosition  = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    vec3 ecPosition3 = ecPosition.xyz / ecPosition.w;

    vec3 i = normalize(ecPosition3);
    vec3 n = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);

    Ratio   = F + (1.0 - F) * pow((1.0 - dot(-i, n)), FresnelPower);

    Refract = refract(i, n, Eta);
    Refract = vec3(gl_TextureMatrix[0] * vec4(Refract, 1.0));

    Reflect = reflect(i, n);
    Reflect = vec3(gl_TextureMatrix[0] * vec4(Reflect, 1.0));

    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

**Fragment shader:**

```
varying vec3  Reflect;
varying vec3  Refract;
varying float Ratio;

uniform samplerCube Cubemap;

void main()
{
    vec3 refractColor = vec3(textureCube(Cubemap, Refract));
    vec3 reflectColor = vec3(textureCube(Cubemap, Reflect));

    vec3 color   = mix(refractColor, reflectColor, Ratio);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

First thing I notice is the `varying` keyword. I couldn't really find out if this is deprecated or not. I'm using OpenGL 4+. So shouldn't that be changed to `in` or `out`?

Other thing is the `uniform` keyword. That means I have to pass a value from my code to my shader right? In this case I have to pass a cubemap. I guess I can figure out how to create one of those later, that's not important right now. But what I do like to know is how to change the value of the variable. I couldn't really find any info about that.

Comment: What language are you using for your code? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Byte56 I'm using c++. So far i've been able to compile shaders. I tested it with a simple shader which just colored my model. But i'm just not sure how to work with this shader. How to pass data to it etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514050/how-to-update-a-uniform-variable-in-glsl OR http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/glsl_an_introduction/25007/

Comment: I don't think the question should be tagged as C++. As any OpenGL binding can use GLSL shader code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm using opengl 4+.

No you're not. You are using GLSL 1.10. That's what happens when you do not put a `#version` declaration at the top of your shaders.

If you want to use GLSL version 4.10 or 4.20, you have to ask for it: `#version 4.20`.

As for `varying`, yes, that was deprecated in GLSL 1.30 and removed in GLSL 1.40. You should be using `in` and `out`.

> Other thing is the 'uniform' keyword. That means i have to pass a value from my code to my shader right? In this case i have to pass a cubemap. I guess i can figure out how to create one of those later, that's not important right now. But what i do like to know is how to change the value of the variable. I couldn't really find any info about that...

Did you look? The [top](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/) [two](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Uniform) hits on Google for "GLSL uniform" explain how they work. "OpenGL uniform" resolves to similarly useful pages.

However, for the record:

A global variable using the `uniform` qualifier means that the value of this variable is set from outside of the shader. The value is "uniform" over the execution of a single `glDraw` call. The API functions that set uniform values for GLSL programs all start with [`glUniform`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glUniform).

`uniform` variables of `sampler` types are special. They represent textures. [More details can be found on the wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Sampler).